# trying to print error message on key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to print a error message when someone types in a wrong value in the input field but I have no idea how to do this. If random value is 6 and the user types in 7, then a user message popup shows up saying "you have wrong entry".

```
function RandomNum(min, max) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
let key1 = RandomNum(1, 10)
let key2 = RandomNum(1, 10)
$("#rnd1").html(key1.toString() + " + " + key2.toString())

$("#submit").click(() => {
  alert(parseInt($("#rnd2").val()) === (key1 + key2))
})



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Human test <span id="rnd1"></span></p>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="rnd2">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="validate">
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Here is screenshot .need error message like this 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```js
function RandomNum(min, max) {
  return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}
let key1 = RandomNum(1, 10)
let key2 = RandomNum(1, 10)
$("#rnd1").html(key1.toString() + " + " + key2.toString())

$("#rnd2").on("keyup", (e) => {
  $("#error").hide();
  
  if(parseInt($("#rnd2").val()) !== (key1 + key2)){
    $("#error").show();
  }
  else{
    $("#error").hide();
    $("#not-error").show();
  }
})
```

```css
#error{
  position : absolute;
bottom: 0;
  background : red;
  display : none
}

#not-error{
  position : absolute;
bottom: 0;
  background : green;
  display : none
  color : white
}

#box{
  position : relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div id="box">
    <input type="text" id="rnd2">
    <span id="error">You have wrong entry</span>
    <span id="not-error">valid</span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="validate">
</form>

<p>Human test <span id="rnd1"></span></p>
```

Comment: elasmai elmehdi@ok its awesome . but can we do this without clicking on validate button. when i write 9 then get error message you are robot @pleasse see the updated question

Comment: elasmai elmehdi@you there ??

Comment: /elasmai elmehdi@hey you there?

Comment: elasmai elmehdi@you there i neeed a message on key press

Comment: elasmai elmehdi@hello you there